npm install hang on pipeline server
I am using angular 17.3.10 and npm install is working locally, but on the build server, it is hanging while installing packages. I have tried to force, clean, delete the package-lock file etc., but it is still having the same issue.
I tried to clean, verbose, delete package-lock, and update node version 20.15.1 to 20.16.0 but no luck.

What specs does the server have? It could be a RAM issue. You could check that by for example using the htop command while running the install

Nirmala give you the "key". Install a node and typescript that fullfilled Angular requirements. Note: you can use nvm to co-living" diferents nodejs version

Try to downgrade npm first:
npm install -g npm@10.8.0


Try to install compatible node version.
https://angular.dev/reference/versions

